# how to give border in table rows, the border length depends on the column content?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want give border for my table. in that the border for every column depends on the content in that column and not in the full length of that column.
I tried border-collapse property and border-bottom, but it gives the border through out the column.
anyone help me please..

thanks in advance..

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS, preferable as a Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Unless the content is static, you won't be able to do this with pure css. You'll need to use something like javascript/jquery.

Comment: You can "hack" it and add cells into your table that act as a "border" where they are filled in with color. Set them with a % and they will inherit a length according to column content

Answer (score 0):

try `table {border-spacing: 0;}` (no collapse!) and `tr {border:solid;}`